# How to re-use oauth2 token in rest assured test cases

Tags: java, rest-assured

Say I have a test case like this

```
given().
    auth().oauth2(API_TOKEN).
    param("name", "new name").
when().
     post(API_HOST + "/create").
then().
    statusCode(200);
```

Following this example https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#specification-re-use I am able to create a method like this

```
public static RequestSpecification setBaseUri() {
    RequestSpecBuilder builder = new RequestSpecBuilder();
    builder.setBaseUri(API_HOST);
    return builder.build();
}
```

and now the test case becomes like this

```
given().
    spec(setBaseUri()).
    auth().oauth2(API_TOKEN).
    param("name", "new name").
when().
     post("/create").
then().
    statusCode(200);
```

But how can I pass in auth with oauth2, with specified API_TOKEN, so that I can also remove the line  *auth().oauth2(API_TOKEN).* from all test cases?

Also is this something that can be done through a TestRule, so that even the line spec(..) can be removed?

Answer (score 0):

You can add auth and param in spec like this:

```
RequestSpecification requestSpec = new RequestSpecBuilder().
        setContentType(ContentType.JSON).
        addHeader("Authorization", "yourtoken").
        addParam(yor param). // or you can add body like set.body
        build();
```